# How to simulate operation with two fingers in MonkeyRunner

Tags: android, monkeyrunner

I'm developing automation tests for "map viewer" app with MonkeyRunner on Android and I'm stuck on zooming and changing the view angle. In those tests I need to simulate move of two fingers simultaneously on the screen.
I was looking on device.drag() and device.touch() methods but don't know exactly how to use them in this case.